# SF Flows: Error handling in screen flows

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I am working on a screen flow which will call an invocable action. The LWC component which initializes the flow in not in my team's domain and may not be handling errors. I am wondering if I create fault paths with error screens in my flow, will the initializing component still receive the error status? If not, I will need to figure out how to send the error status to the initializing component.

For example, if the user sees a modal that an error was encountered in the flow and they close the modal, will the initializing component receive the 'error' status or does that need to be manually stored in a variable and sent to the initializing LWC component?

Any advice on how to best handle this would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/superbadges/superbadge_flow_error_handling_sbu